# How to use QFileSystemModel to filter multiple directories and show them on QTreeView?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, pyside

How do I use `QFileSystemModel` to filter several directories in PyQt4 and show them on a `QTreeView`?

I try to

1. subclass `QFileSystemModel`, but I do not know how to return the `rowCount`
2. use `QSortFilterProxyModel -> filterAcceptsRow()`, but it is difficult
   to return
3. `QFileSystemWatcher` is not good.

Maybe I did not do the right things.

Should I through win32 to monitor the directories and create my own Model and Node?

for example 1
[image]

for example 2
[image]

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from functools import partial
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore


disk = 'C:/'
dir_1 = 'C:/Python27'
dir_1_1 = 'C:/Python27/Lib'
dir_1_1_1 = 'C:/Python27/Lib/bsddb'


class FilterProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FilterProxyModel, self).__init__()
        self.count = 0

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, src_row, src_parent):

        src_model = self.sourceModel()
        src_index = src_model.index(src_row, 0, src_parent)

        item_data = src_model.itemData(src_parent)
        # print 'item_data: ', item_data
        item_var = src_index.data(Qt.DisplayRole)
        # print 'item_var: ', item_var

        file_path = src_model.filePath(src_index)
        file_path = str(file_path)
        if disk in file_path:
            # print 'file_path: ', file_path
            if file_path == disk:
                # print 'file_path: ', file_path
                return True

            elif dir_1 == file_path:
                # print 'file_path: ', file_path
                return True

            elif dir_1_1 == file_path:
                # print 'file_path: ', file_path
                return True

            elif dir_1_1_1 == file_path:
                # print 'file_path: ', file_path
                return True

            elif file_path.endswith('.py'):
                print 'file_path: ', file_path
                return True

        return False



class MyQFileSystemModel(QFileSystemModel):
    """docstring for MyQFileSystemModel"""
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyQFileSystemModel, self).__init__(parent)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 1


class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.pathRoot = QDir.rootPath()

        # self.model = QFileSystemModel(self)
        self.model = MyQFileSystemModel(self)
        self.model.setRootPath(self.pathRoot)
        self.model.setNameFilterDisables(0)


        filter = ['*.py', '*mll']
        self.model.setNameFilters(filter)
        self.model.setNameFilterDisables(0)
        # self.model.removeColumn(2)

        self.proxy = FilterProxyModel()
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)
        self.proxy.setDynamicSortFilter(True)

        self.treeView = QTreeView(self)
        self.treeView.setModel(self.proxy)
        # self.treeView.setRootIndex(self.indexRoot)
        # self.listView = QListView(self)
        # self.listView.setModel(self.proxy)


        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.treeView)
        # self.layout.addWidget(self.listView)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow()
    main.resize(666, 333)

    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I just do this.
At the end, I give up, I use another method.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @ekhumoro It's not a debugging question, so a code example is not needed. The shown images are enough to get the idea of what is wanted, I think.

Comment: thanks for your answer

Comment: @Trilarion. Agrred about the images, but the OP also suggested they had tried some solutions and couldn't get them to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was exactly in your situation, and found something. The trick is to get a list of paths you want to hide, and pass it to your treeView with the setHiddenRow method. This is what I wrote before the addWidget method

```
# hide all no desired folders.
foldersToShow = []
for currentDir, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootPath): 
    if currentDir in "/folder/I/want/to/show" : #whatever condition you prefer, this is your main filter for what you want to KEEP
        foldersToShow.append(currentDir)
    else:
        index = self.model.index(currentDir)
        self.treeView.setRowHidden(index.row(), index.parent(), True) # what doesnt meet your requirements get to be hidden
```

From here, there is an issue. The files in the folders you want to keep are not displayed for a reason I don't get. But there is a way to display them. From each directory, turn false the rowHidden argument of each file

```
# display all files from foldersToShow
for folder in foldersToShow:
    for currentDir, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(folder):
        for filename in filenames:
            filenamePath = os.path.join(currentDir.replace(r"/",'\\'), filename)
            fileId = self.model.index(filenamePath)
            self.treeView.setRowHidden(fileId.row(), fileId.parent(), False)

layout.addWidget(self.treeView)
```