# PyQt5 adding a folder to QFileSystemModel

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qfilesystemmodel

I am trying to make a QListView where it only shows specific folders on my computer. Note that the folders can be in separate directories.
I am using QFileSystemModel for my QListView, but cannot find a method that appends a folder to the end of my QFileSystemModel.
I am aware that I can filter, but that does not solve my problem, because the folders that I want to appear is not in the QFileSystemModel.

For example, here is a folder that I want to show and one that I do *not* want to show:

[image]

and inside the folder `folder that I want to hide`, there is a file I do not want to show and a folder that I do want to show:

[image]

Is there a way to force my QFileSystemModel to include specific folders anywhere on my computer?

Comment: What do you mean by "is not in the QFileSystemModel"? If the folder is on your computer it means that it "exists" for the model. Have you checked this? [How to use QFileSystemModel to filter multiple directories and show them on QTreeView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266719/how-to-use-qfilesystemmodel-to-filter-multiple-directories-and-show-them-on-qtre) Note that that answer seems to have some issues (probably due to the delayed loading the model uses, which probably needs a more accurate implementation of [`fetchMore()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#fetchMore).

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc hmm... I am not sure what code to include. My problem is not a bug, but a lack of understanding on how to add a path to QFileSystemModel.